# How to render a view when el was deleted?

Tags: backbone.js

When the view is loaded during the first request, the collection is added to the view as desired:

```
    showMainpage: function() {
      console.log('show mainpage');
      var sidebar = new SidebarView();

      $("#maincontent").html(new SimpleItemsView().render().el);
    },
```

with SimpleItemsView:

```
  var SimpleItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#overview"),
    tagName: "tbody",
```

However, when the DOM changes, and the part of the #maincontent changes, the #overview element can not be resolved anymore, see:

[image: overview disappears]

How can I re-render the #overview part? The project is also here: https://github.com/mulderp/backbone-require-test/blob/master/public/js/app.js#L31

Comment: Using `el` means that `tagName` will be ignored so don't use both. Why not use a template for `#overview`?

Comment: yes, thanks for the feedback... I've made it work indeed by adding a template; actually, part of my problem was the structuring of parent/child view, if you are interested, my current state is in the repo above...